# Left aligned Abstract

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fontsize, abstract

The following is an example code. I want to make the title of "Abstract" left-aligned. And how to change the size of "Abstract"? Thank you for answers!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `abstract` environment to meet your criteria:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\small\quotation
  {\bfseries\noindent{\large\abstractname}\par\nobreak\smallskip}}
  {\endquotation}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]